# concatenate two strings without strcat

Tags: c, string, strcat

I want to concatenate two strings without using strcat() function.But I am not getting the required result. Please point me my mistake.

```
void main() {
    char s1[100], s2[100];
    int i;

    puts("First string?");
    gets(s1);

    puts("Second string?");
    gets(s2);

    for (i = strlen(s1); i <= (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2)); i++) {
        s1[i] = s2[i - strlen(s1)];
    }

    puts(s1);
}
```

Comment: Step through the code, line by line, in a debugger, and it should be pretty obvious. Also don't use `gets`, it's been obsolete since the C99 standard, and removed in the C11 standard.

Comment: Despite the solution, NEVER use gets (the manpage itself states this). It does not check the boundaries of your buffer, so it is _very_ unsafe.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: I know it was a silly terrible mistake .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't really change much in your program, but here's what I have (modified from yours) and it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
  {
    char s1[100], s2[100];
    size_t i, s1l, s2l, total;

    puts("First string?");
    fgets(s1, sizeof(s1), stdin);
    s1[strlen(s1) - 1] = 0x00;

    puts("Second string?");
    fgets(s2, sizeof(s2), stdin);
    s2[strlen(s2) - 1] = 0x00;

    s1l = strlen(s1);
    s2l = strlen(s2);
    total = s1l + s2l;

    for(i = s1l; i <= total; i++)
      {
        s1[i] = s2[i - s1l];
      }

    puts(s1);

    return(0);
  }
```

Using your program verbatim, the problem was that since the length of s1 was changing at each iteration of the loop, the strlen(s1) in the check kept increasing in value so you would basically end up with a mostly infinite loop...at least until it encountered some random null byte.  However, when taking the length of the strings before hand, the loop terminus count does not change which results in the proper output.  My code will compile and run correctly on a FreeBSD 10.2 system using the clang compiler.

As a side note, **DO NOT** return void on main.  **ALWAYS** return int.  Also specify the library headers that you plan to use.

EDIT: I modified the code to use fgets instead of gets since gets is completely unsafe.  It does not check buffer sizes so you can easily have a buffer overflow.

Comment: I am not the down voter, but it seems we are in the presence of a real A player today, who's opinions of self are just a little bit too superior.  Your answer by the way provides with it good explanations to the OPs questions.

Comment: I was more interested in answering the OP's question as to why his code did not work.  Then I edit for security considerations and post the edited version.  Stripping the LF char is simple enough.  I'll add that code.

Comment: You are correct.  I missed that little bug.  Probably because I was using test1 and test2 as my input.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variation of sprintf:

simpler

```
char buf[200];
sprintf(buf, "%s%s" s1, s2);
```

simpler *and* safer

```
char buf[200]
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s%s", s1, s2);//prevents buffer overflow
```

Or, modify your loop (see in line comments for why):

```
int main(void)//note changed main prototype
{
        char s1[100], s2[100];//caution here: s1 must be big enough
                              //to contain its string as well as
                              //the string stored in s2, plus 1 for NULL
        int i;
        int len1, len2;//create variables to store string lengths

        puts("First string?");
        gets(s1);//note, gets is no longer recommended

        puts("Second string?");
        gets(s2);
        len1 = strlen(s1);//store string lengths only once
        len2 = strlen(s2);//to avoid calling them repeatedly in loop

        for(i = 0; i < len2; i++)//index i in one place only
        {
            s1[len1+i] = s2[i];
        }
        s1[len1 + i]=0;//null terminate string when done.
        puts(s1);
        getchar();//added to pause execution in my environment.
        return 0;
}
```

A sample session using the above modifications is shown here:
[image]

Comment: Because it's like trying to reinvent the wheel. There are functions that do the same and are probably more safer to use.

Comment: Your algorithm isn't wrong but it's inefficient. You are calling strlen three times for each loop iteration.

Comment: Remove the `gets` too!

Comment: @chqrlie - Edited `<=` to `<`

Answer (score 1):

The length of s1 is getting changed at runtime, making your index i incorrect. Try something like below:-

```
l = strlen(s1);

for(i = 0; i < strlen(s2); i++)
{
   s1[l++] = s2[i];
}

s1[l] = '\0';
```

Suppose s1 = "hello" and s2 = "world", then in the first iteration length of s1 = 5 and index for s2 = 0(i- length(s1)); works well. But in the second iteration length(s1) = 6 and index for s2 = 0(i-length(s1)). so index for taking the character from s2 is not changing. This was about the problem in your implementation, though you should an efficient way by using sprintf.

```
sprintf(s1, "%s%s", s1, s2);
```

Comment: `l` looks dangerously similar to `1`...  better rename this variable as `len`.

Comment: he wants to know what is the problem in the current implementation, so problem is indexing. obviously one should use sprintf.

Comment: Actually, `sprintf(s1, "%s%s", s1, s2);` invokes undefined behavior because `s1` is both the destination and one of the source arguments.

Comment: I'm afraid you are not seeing the obvious.  You cannot pass the same buffer as the output array for `sprintf` and an input for format `%s`.  Your code might miraculously produce what you expect, but it is in no way guaranteed.  C11 7.21.6.6: *The sprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the output is written into an array (specified by the argument s) rather than to a stream. A null character is written at the end of the characters written; it is not counted as part of the returned value. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.*

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not work because you recompute `strlen(s1)` upon each iteration to test for completion and to figure the offset in `s2` to copy a character from, but you modify `s1` in the loop, so the length changes, and even worse, `s1` is temporarily no longer `'\0'` terminated: the test expression `i <= strlen(s1) + strlen(s2)` invokes undefined behavior, and the same happens when you copy `s2[i - strlen(s1)]` the second time through the loop.

Use these ideas to correct your code:

- do not use `gets` to read input, use `fgets()` and remove the final `'\n'`.
- compute the length of `s1` and `s2` only once and store them in local variables.
- verify that the concatenation will not exceed the size of `s1`.
- rewrite your loop with these local variables, or use `strcpy` or `memcpy`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char s1[100], s2[100];
    size_t i, len1, len2;

    puts("First string?");
    if (!fgets(s1, sizeof s1, stdin))
        return 1;

    len1 = strlen(s1);
    if (len1 > 0 && s1[len1 - 1] == '\n')
        s1[--len1] = '\0';

    puts("Second string?");
    if (!fgets(s2, sizeof s2, stdin))
        return 1;

    len2 = strlen(s2);
    if (len2 > 0 && s2[len2 - 1] == '\n')
        s1[--len2] = '\0';

    if (len1 + len2 >= sizeof s1)
        return 2;

    /* copy the characters from s2 including the final '\0' */
    for (i = 0; i <= len2; i++) {
        s1[len1 + i] = s2[i];
    }

    puts(s1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// A simple strcat function

int main(void)
{
    char str1[100] ="Avis";
    stringcat(str1,"karthik");
    printf("\n%s",str1);
    return 0;
}
void stringcat(char *str1, char *str2)
{
   while(*str1)
       str1++;
   while(*str2)
       *str1++ = *str2++;
}
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar!  You forgot to copy the final `'\0'`.  Rewrite your second loop this way: `while ((*str1++ = *str2++) != '\0') continue;`